Compiling and Linking Matplot++
So, I'm recently install C++ library called Matplot++, basically like Matplotlib but for C++, i install it in Termux, the thing is, i have no idea how to Link the library to my source file.
Does anyone have any idea to Link it?

How you link a library depends on the IDE/compiler you are using. Maybe that is implied by your other tags, but it wouldn't hurt to specify it explicitly in the question.

For compiling, i uses g++

Then to link with a library you use the -l option. Something like -lmatplotplusplus but exactly what you need to put depends on exactly what the library file is called.

Which part of the official documentation is confusing for you?

Or if you want to invoke compiler explicitly by had, https://github.com/alandefreitas/matplotplusplus/blob/master/examples/CMakeLists.txt#L3 name of the library is matplot

The thing is that, i install it from the source, and the header file is called "matplot.h"
